# How to test window.getSelection() using React/Karma/Jasmine?

Tags: reactjs, jasmine, karma-runner, webpack

I have this test:

```
  it("should allow to set the caret position", ->
    editor = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument <Editor />
    editor.setContent(lines)
    editor.setCaretPosition(6)
    selection = window.getSelection();
    expect(selection.anchorNode.outerHTML).toBe("<span>      <br /></span>");
  )
```

and here is my setCaretPosition method

```
  setCaretPosition: (lineNumber) ->
    elem = React.findDOMNode this
    elem.focus()
    line = elem.childNodes[lineNumber]
    range = document.createRange()
    range.setStart(line.firstChild, line.textContent.length)
    range.setEnd(line.firstChild, line.textContent.length)
    selection = window.getSelection()
    selection.removeAllRanges()
    selection.addRange(range)
    return selection
```

But the selection returned from the setCaretPosition has a rangeCount set to 0, meaning that the addRange didn't work.

I'm not sure what is wrong. I'm using Webpack, React, Jasmine and Karma with Chrome Launcher. Anyone has any idea of how to make this test to work?